# Show that $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ be an entire function.If for each $z\in \Bbb C$ $\exists$ a positive integer $n$ such that $f^n(z)=0$ then show that $f$ is a polynomial

**My try**:
Since $f$ is entire $f$ has  a power series expansion about say a point $a$.

Then $f(z)=c_0+c_1(z-a)+...+c_n(z-a)^n+...\forall z$ where $c_n=\dfrac{f^n(a)}{n!}$

Then by given hypothesis for the given $a\in \Bbb C ;\exists m$ such that $c_m=\dfrac{f^m(a)}{m!}=0\implies f^m(a)=0$  and this holds forall $a\in \Bbb C$.

Since $\Bbb N$ is countable and $\Bbb C$ is uncountable so there exists at least one $n$ such that $f^n(a)=0$ for uncountable number of $a\in \Bbb C$. So an entire function can only have countable number of zeros so $f^n(z)\equiv 0$. So $f$ is a polynomial.

But I can't figure out if its correct or not.Please help me to figure it out.Is there any flaw in logic.

Comment: I think he wants to prove it with complex analysis methods.

Comment: How is this question the same as the given one@Jonas

Comment: The other one is (and I'm pretty sure there are a few more duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe that
$$\mathbb{C} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} M_n$$
with
$$M_n := \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid f^n(z) = 0\}.$$
What do you know about the cardinality of $M_n$?